# How can I run multiple definitions under a single class?

Tags: python, class, testing, automation, definition

I am trying to create a class with several definitions (constructors?), however when I run the class it is only running the first def that I have written and not the second one, code example below:

```
class Test(baseline):

 def test_1(self):
    global caseid
    caseid = xxx
    global resultfail
    resultfail = "Test Failed."
    self.driver.get(self.base_url)
    self.login()
    print('Test 1')
    self.Test1TestCase()

 def test_2(self):
    self.driver.get(self.base_url)
    self.login()
    print('Test 2')
    self.Test2TestCase()
```

Could someone please advise what changes I need to make for the Class to run both definitions? Or if this is even possible under a single Class? Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean "run both definitions"?  Your code doesn't call either of the functions you defined.

Comment: what do you mean "when I run the class"? How exactly are you using this class? When you say "definition", do you mean method? Have you tried instantiating a `Test` object and calling the methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class `Test` , I am assuming `baseline` is a super-class since you are defining class `Test` with it.

You haven't created a constructor that will help class instances to be established.

```
  class Test(baseline):

  def __init__(self):
      #initialize something
```

Next, you need to call and instantiate `Test` class within main (outside class)

```
sampleTest = Test()  #instance of Test
```

Then you can call "methods" (functions) within class `Test` as,

```
sampleTest.test_1()
sampleTest.test_2()
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.